# after upgrade ubuntu from 15.04 to 16.04, tor obfs4 ClientTransportPlugin isn't work

Tags: 16.04, tor

today i upgrade ubuntu from 15.04 to 16.04, after that my tor is down and i have the problem on /var/log/tor/log :

> Apr 25 07:52:58.678 [warn] OpenSSL version from headers does not match the version we're running with. If you get weird crashes, that might be why. (Compiled with 1000207f: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016; running with 1000207f: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016).
>
> Apr 25 07:52:58.702 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips and Zlib 1.2.8.
>   Apr 25 07:52:58.702 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
>   Apr 25 07:52:58.702 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
>
> Apr 25 07:52:58.702 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
>   Apr 25 07:52:58.705 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
>   Apr 25 07:52:58.706 [notice] Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
>
> Apr 25 07:52:58.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
>   Apr 25 07:52:58.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
>
> Apr 25 07:52:58.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
>   Apr 25 07:52:58.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
>
> Apr 25 07:52:58.000 [notice] Signaled readiness to systemd
>   Apr 25 07:52:59.000 [warn] Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' ('Operation not permitted').
>   Apr 25 07:53:00.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
>
> Apr 25 07:53:00.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '192.210.206.101:38617' using pluggable transport 'obfs4', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs4'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
>
> Apr 25 07:53:00.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Can't connect to bridge; PT_MISSING; count 1; recommendation warn; host 9E255A5456143C435D0EADAB1473A3884A29C8C4 at 192.210.206.101:38617)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a problem in the tor package which makes it against apparmor rules to let tor run the obfs4proxy as root. The quickest workaround is to run tor as a normal user and not root. to do so, first stop the tor service:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop tor.service
```

and run tor as your own user:

```
$ tor
```

The other way is to change apparmor rules, but this need a deep understanding of apparmor. You can see [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/obfsproxy-problem-in-ubuntu/4013) for getting the idea, but I'm not sure this will fix this since I'm not an expert in apparmor.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tor/+bug/1568435) is the reported and confirmed bug.